# AngularJS function execution sequence question

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio

I am using calling function  Save_Click in Angular controller on button click.

Following is the sequence of execution

```
Line Code 
1    Declare a variable V1 
2    console.log(V1) 
3    Perform a server post back, and assign a value to V1 depending on the values the service returns. console.log(V1)
4 console.log(V1)
```

What I see is that - in console #4 is printed before - #3
Also the value assigned in #3 is not printed in #4.

What could be the reason? What I am doing wrong?
I get the same issue if I use $localStorage (ngStorage) library too.

Note - I am using Visual Studio/.Net solution to host the angular application in my Index.cshtml.

Comment: Its the natural behavior of asynchronous code. Some code blocks like the http service, events are asynchronous. When an asynchronous code block reaches,#3 in your case, program will invoke that statement and continue executing the next statement, code against the asynchronous code will execute once it completes the async operation. That's why #4 (non asynch) proints before #3 (async code).

Comment: How to make sure that the asynchronous code gets executed first?

Comment: In order to do that, you need to break the asynchronous behavior. ES6 is giving `async` and `await` feature. https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: await will wait until the operation finishes. Please make sure that await will work only inside an async function

Comment: using the following - to the service function doesn't seem to make a change.
CallAPI:  async function (ServiceURL, objectToSerialize) {

     

                    var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + ":94/api/Message/" + ServiceURL + "/";
                    console.log(url);
                    var req = {
                        method: 'PUT',
                        url: url
                        , data: objectToSerialize
                    };
                   

                    return await $http(req);
                }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below method

```
1    Declare a variable V1 
2    console.log(V1) 
3    async (Perform a server post back, and assign a value to V1 depending on the values the service returns. await console.log(V1))
4    console.log(V1)
```

Now #3 will prints before #4

Answer (score 0):

Finally did the trick for me.

```
var x = {};
            
                    x.1 = '1';
                    x.2 = '2';
                   
                    MyService.CallAPI('RunRabbit', x).success(function (data) {
                        if (data === null) {
                            $scope.error = true;
                            $scope.errorDescription = "No data found for selected criteria.";
                            
                        } else {
                           
                            $scope.answer = data.answer;
                           
                        }
                    }).error(function () {

                    }).finally(function () {
                        console.log($scope.answer);
                    });
```

I could evaluate $scope.answer and then use it in synchronous way from finally.